# Why I am getting a System.NullReferenceException with this foreach loop when using IsChecked

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid where I am trying to catch a list of Item Codes that get "Checked" by the user. In stepping through the code with the debugger I know that it is getting all the records that are checked. But it seems to me that when it reaches the last row it is trying to get another because I get a "System.NullReferenceException' occurred in appname" error at the time that all the records have been read. This is my code.

```
    private void btnMarkRecords_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> lstItemCodes = new List<string>();
        foreach (var row in dgAdmin.ItemsSource)
        {
            bool IsChecked = (bool)((CheckBox)dgAdmin.Columns[8].GetCellContent(row)).IsChecked;

            if (IsChecked)
            {
                string itemCode = ((TextBlock)dgAdmin.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row)).Text;
                lstItemCodes.Add(itemCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

I admit that I am speculating that moving past the last row is what is causing the NullReferenceException but I am not sure why else I would be gettng this error. So assuming that it is what do I need to do to stop at the last row. And if it is not please tell me what it is that I am doing wrong here.

**Edit:** Edit to add the XAML

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="dgAdmin"
                      Height="380"
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      Width="900">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Store"
                                        Binding="{Binding StoreId}"
                                        Width="43" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category"
                                        Binding="{Binding CategoryCode}"
                                        Width="150"
                                        MinWidth="100" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ItemCode"
                                        Binding="{Binding ItemCode}"
                                        Width="120*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="End Qty"
                                        Binding="{Binding EndQuantity}"
                                        Width="90" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Items On Rcvr"
                                        Binding="{Binding OpenReceiversIncludedInCount}"
                                        Width="90" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Final Count"
                                        Binding="{Binding FinalCountQuantity}"
                                        Width="90" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adjusted Qty"
                                        Binding="{Binding AdjustedQuantity}"
                                        Width="90" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adjusted $"
                                        Binding="{Binding AdjustedDollars}"
                                        Width="90" />
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Recounts"
                                            Width="80" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Do you break when the exception is thrown so you can inspect the values of each object? A CheckBox's `IsChecked` property is of type `bool?`, so the value could be null, as well.

Comment: The bool isChecked line is throwing the exception. Looking at that values of the objects confuses me more. I had thought that I was reaching the end of the grid but based on what you said I looked at the .GetCellContent(row)).IsChecked in debug mode and I see that the error is not the last record. It is just a record about a third of the way down the grid.Checking different records gives me different results but I am not sure of what the pattern is. It could be null but since this is just a checkbox added in the XAML I am not sure why the state of one Checkbox would be different from another.

Comment: How can it be an ItemsSource when it has no binding?

Comment: why don't you break dgAdmin.Columns[8].GetCellContent(row)).IsChecked 
into several lines of code and see what's actually null 

var dataGrid = dgAdmin ;
var c8 = dataGrid.Columns[8] ;
var content = c8.GetCellContent(row) ;
var checkBox = content as CheckBox;
var isChecked = checkBox.IsChecked;

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Iterate the ItemsSource to get Rows, because it contains the DataItems. From the DataItem you can get the row. Refer below code.

```
 foreach (var item in dgr.ItemsSource)
        {
            var row = dgr.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
            bool IsChecked = (bool)((CheckBox)dgr.Columns[8].GetCellContent(row)).IsChecked;

            if (IsChecked)
            {
                string itemCode = ((TextBlock)dgr.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row)).Text;
                lstItemCodes.Add(itemCode);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I get the same error with this version of the code block also.

Comment: Do you mean the XAML? I am asking because other then setting the ItemsSource there is no other code. I am setting the ItemsSource like this dgAdmin.ItemsSource = StoreCounts.PostCountAdmin.getPostCountNumbersAdmin("A19",30,4,2015).DefaultView;

Comment: Edited original post to include XAML